# How to combine two integers into one string using C?

Tags: c, string, int, printf

> I have two integers and I want to combine them into one string in the
>   following way: for example, given `xx=555`, `yy=3`, I want the string to be:
>   "`555-03`". The value in `yy` resembles hours in my case, so it has to contain
>   two digits, but days it doesn't matter and there is a difference
>   between "`555-03`" and "`555-3`". Any ideas how I can do something like
>   this?

this basicly i get the following error :function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
My try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char* intToTimeDate(int day,int hour);
int main()
{
    int hour=5555;
    int curr_day=7;

    char* curr_time=intToTimeDate(curr_day,hour);
    printf("dd=%s",curr_time);
    return 0;
}


static char* intToTimeDate(int day,int hour){
          char str[16];
           snprintf ( str, sizeof ( str) - 1, "%d-%02d", day,hour);
           printf("str=%s",str);
           return str;
        }
```

Comment: Start by checking how `printf` works: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/. `sprintf` does the same but writes the output into given string.

Comment: Haven't you ever used [any of the `printf` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print out multiple values in a single call? You can have quite a few format specifications in the format string.

Comment: does this work for the two integers ??

Comment: and how it knows the size ??

Comment: What output  with `xx=555 yy=-3` .  If `yy` can not be negative, what are all the range restrictions on `xx,yy`?

Comment: xx could be any number buy yy resemble an hour so it must be between 0 and 23 also i want the string to have only two places to the hour as i saied above if the hour is 3 i want to save it in the string as 03 and if its 44  i want to save it as 44

Comment: this didn't work the program stopped suddenly

Comment: What is the difference between `555-3` and `555-03`?  You mention "if it is 44, I want to save it as 44", but you previously said in the same comment that the range is 0 to 23, so it is confusing?  It's all pretty much trivial once the specification is clear.  Assuming `xxx` is 555, if the `yy` value is 3, you want `555-03`; if it is 0, you want `555-00`, if it is 10, you want `555-10` — is that correct? And if `xxx` is just 90, you want `90-10`; and if it is 8, you want `8-10`; and if it is 0, you want `0-10`?  A single call to `sprintf()` is all that's needed.  The format string is not hard.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i want !!!!

Comment: i wrote this to check it but it is not working :

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    int xx=555;
    int yy=3;
    char* str=NULL;
   snprintf ( str, sizeof ( str) - 1, "%d-%02d", xx, yy);
   printf("str=%s",str);

  return 0;
}

Comment: ok i will update the question i cab't put a code in the comments

Comment: You need an array, not a pointer to nowhere, for the call to `sprintf()`.  Use `char str[32];` and you'd be good to go.  You can use either `%02d` or `%.2d` to get the 2-digits with leading zero when necessary.  There's a partial case for saying the `%.2d` notation is better, but it's a bit tenuous.

Comment: ok this works like this but the peoblem i want to use this in function that return char* i will update the question so you could see what i mean

Comment: thank you so uch it worked !! as soon i get time i will learn sprintf

Comment: returning str is illegal. Its a local variable, you need to malloc a string to return

Comment: Is this a coding workshop? Questions shouldn't be "moving targets".

Comment: looooooooooooooooool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's code works except that it returns a pointer to a local variable which is UB once the function ends.  Instead pass a pointer to valid memory to store the result.

```
static char* intToTimeDate(char *str, int day,int hour){
   sprintf(str, "%d-%02d", day, hour);
   printf("str=%s",str);
   return str;
}
```

The destination string should be wide enough to accommodate *any* pair of `int` values.

A solution to return a pointer to a *string* involves allocating the *string*.  With C99 onward, code can use a *compound literal* for temporary space.  The pointer returned from `intToTimeDate()` is valid until the end of the block - the lifetime of the *compound literal*.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char* intToTimeDate(char *str, int day, int hour) {
  sprintf(str, "%d-%02d", day, hour);
  return str;
}

// Size needed to store a decimal string verison of `int`
#define INT_DEC_SIZE (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
//                         v--- compound literal ----------------------v
#define INTTOTIMEDATE(d,y) (intToTimeDate((char [INT_DEC_SIZE*2 + 2]){0}, (d), (y)))

int main(void) {
  puts(INTTOTIMEDATE(555, 3));  // Output "555-03\n"
  return 0;
}
```